# Free SMS API integration with my Web App

Tags: api, sms

I need to build a web application that sends a free SMS to its users. Now the problem is That I have no clue as to where do I get a free API to get this to work and how? Can someone help?

Comment: There are a huge variety of free SMS APIs available. I just searched for "free SMS API" on Google and got back lots of results. Did you have a more specific question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Free SMS API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238579/free-sms-api)

Comment: You may think this is not a real question but it did answer exactly what I needed to know... and my question was a real question just as the OP's was.

Answer (score 8):

I believe most of the 'free' APIs make their money with ads embedded in your messages or sent along as a separate message. Additionally, the messages will likely come from a shared short code. If you're okay with those limitations, as @anirvan commented, google is your friend - here's just [one example](http://www.zeepmobile.com/). Unlikely that you'll get wide international support (if that's something you need).

You could also try the email to SMS route, as many carriers will accept email to a unique address and forward that to the user. Again, google can help in [finding those mappings](http://www.mutube.com/projects/open-email-to-sms/gateway-list/). Note that the messages may not be in a desirable format, and if you do this with any volume, you may incur the wrath of the carriers.

There's also low cost APIs - certainly not free - but perhaps worth considering depending on your use case. Here are a few:

- [Nexmo](http://nexmo.com)
- [Twilio](http://twilio.com)
- [Tropo](http://tropo.com)

If cost is your main concern, I think you'll find Nexmo has the most competitive prices.

**Disclosure**: I'm a developer evangelist for Nexmo.